# Traffic has dropped to zero in Google Analytics but impressions and clicks are recorded in Search Console

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

For some strange reason, the data in Search Console is persistent but Google Analytics has reported a sharp drop in the traffic to almost zero.

Here is my last 28 days data for both:

- Search Console:

[image: Search Console Report]

- Google Analytics: https://ibb.co/LJVMHMD

[image: Google Analytics]

I haven't changed anything in Google Analytics. I have 301 permanent redirected my old domain to my current domain. Search console and tracking are set up for the current domain only.

Can anyone please help me understand what has happened in Analytics? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The chrome extensions "Tag Assistant" and "GA Debug" should help you test if your tracking code is working.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath they are working fine.

Comment: Try visiting the site and checking for your presence in the realtime report. I'd also double check the views filters to make sure nothing is blocking all traffic there.

Comment: I am having the same exact problem! Since October 16th my Google Analytics traffic has dropped to just 4 visits per day (the LOWEST it has been since I started) and yet Google Search Console says my traffic is typical at 50 ish site visits from google per day. I have run the Google Tag which is fine and checked the UA code. I am able to see the Realtime Tracker and it's accurate. There must be something wrong with Google Analytics if we are having the same thing happen to both of us?

Comment: Hi @JenicaBarrett. As I couldn't find out what was wrong so I installed a new Google Analytics code. And everything became normal after that. Make sure you use the new Google Analytics to enjoy some new features. Instead of tracking code, you will now use the Measurement code.